# Uses of self referencing lists

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic, list, self-reference

I know it is possible to create a self referencing list in languages like Python:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2]
>>> my_list.append(my_list)
>>> print my_list
[1,2,[...]]
>>> print my_list[0]
1
>>> print my_list[2]
[1,2,[...]]
```

What algorithms benefit from self referencing lists? I cannot think of one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Self-referencing lists, and, generally speaking, circular data structures, can be caused when representing a graph using data structures.

For example, consider this naive representation of a graph: Each node is either an atomic value, or a list of nodes that it is linked to. A circle may cause a list to contain another list that contains the list. A self-circle, i.e., an edge from a node to itself, will cause a self-referencing list.

Answer (score 0):

Most recursive problem definition uses some kind of self refrential objects or a data with self-referential definition.

I would add the wikipedia link as it provides a good readup:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Others on SO

- [What is recursion and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/what-is-recursion-and-when-should-i-use-it)
- [Recursive Sets vs Recursive Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853409/recursive-sets-vs-recursive-functions)
- [Understanding recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion)
- [Recursive Splay Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374006/recursive-splay-tree)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085834/how-did-you-practically-use-recursion

Comment: Specifically, what problems are you referring to that can be made simpler with lists that contain themselves?

Comment: Thanks for the follow-ups/edits, but what does recursion with self-referencing lists offer that tail-end recursion and self-referencing *method* recursion cannot do and be more expressive at?

Comment: Recursion != Self reference

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking just about lists, then I can't think of something right now, except for maybe recursively creating/searching in a data structure modeled as list.

But one application of a self-referencing could be this [Self Referencing Class Definition in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020279/self-referencing-class-definition-in-python)