# Self-referencing lists

Tags: python

Say you do the following:

```
a = [1]
a[0] = a
```

You end up with `a` as equal to `[[...]]`. What's going on here? How does this implicitly defined infinite chain of `a`'s referring to `a`'s end up as `[[...]]`?

Comment: How is that implicit? You know exactly what you're doing

Comment: `[...]` is how Python represents a self-reference as a string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728667/uses-of-self-referencing-lists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ain't seen nothing:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a[:] = [a] * 4
>>> a
[[...], [...], [...], [...]]
```

If you're interested in how this works in CPython, see [`list_repr` in `listobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/03c65fc349c0/Objects/listobject.c#l361) and similar functions. Basically, any function that potentially prints a self-referential object calls `Py_ReprEnter` on the object before printing it and `Py_ReprLeave` when it is done. (See [`object.c` for the definitions of these functions](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/03c65fc349c0/Objects/object.c#l2358).) The former checks to see if the object is found in a thread-local stack of objects that are currently being printed (and if not, pushes it); the latter pops the object from the stack. So if Python is printing a list and discovers that the list is on the stack, that must mean that this is a self-referential list, and the list should be abbreviated, to avoid an infinite loop:

```
 i = Py_ReprEnter((PyObject*)v);
 if (i != 0) {
     return i > 0 ? PyString_FromString("[...]") : NULL;
 }

 // ...

 Py_ReprLeave((PyObject *)v);
 return result;
```

Answer (score 4):

The list contains a reference to itself. The `[[...]]` is how this is rendered when you print the list.

The implementation goes out of its way to ensure it doesn't end up in an infinite recursion. It does this by rendering references to objects that are already being printed as `[...]`.

This makes it work with indirect self-references too:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [a]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a
[[[...]]]
>>> b
[[[...]]]
```

If you are really curious, you could study CPython's source code. In Python 2.7.3, the relevant code is located in `Objects/listobject.c`.

Comment: Just wanna highlight something for OP, It's not infinite recursion because it's only a **reference**, it doesn't actually try to pass itself by value

Comment: @jamylak: Right. I meant that a method that would try to blindly traverse `a` would end up in infinite recursion.

Comment: Oh I probably should have left that comment on the question, I wasn't referencing your answer

Answer (score 2):

We have `a == [a]` here, so in theory `a` should be printed as a list containing one element, which is `a` --- i.e. itself a list containing one element, which is itself a list containing one element, and so on.  Or in print: an infinite number of `[`, followed by an infinite number of `]`.  The fact that we get instead `[[...]]` is just Python trying to be helpful and not actually printing an infinite number of `[`.